# Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу по JS

Tags: javascript

Вам нужно написать программу, имитирующую лифт Empire State Building:
Спрашивает номер этажа.
Если меньше 1 или более 102, то выводит "неверный этаж".
Если этаж не запаролен – пишет "ок".
Если же запаролен, то просит ввести пароль:
Если пароль равен 1337, то программа пишет "ок"
Иначе – пишет "неверный пароль".
начал писать

```js
let lift = +prompt(" номер этажа?");
if (lift < 1 || lift > 102) {
  console.log("неверный этаж");
} else if (lift < 24 || lift > 39) {
  console.log("ok");
} else if (lift >= 24 || lift <= 39) {
  +prompt("введите пароль");
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как дальше

Comment: password = "1337" if (user_password == password) { ok } else { "password is not correct" }

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложно понять, почему трудно добавить еще одно условие. В данном случае оно вынесенно в функцию, чтобы вынести логику проверки пароля из логик

```js
function checkPassword(password) {
  const result = password === 1337 ? 'ok' : 'неверный пароль'
  console.log(result);
}

let lift = +prompt(" номер этажа?");

if (lift < 1 || lift > 102) {
  console.log("неверный этаж");
} else if (lift < 24 || lift > 39) {
  console.log("ok");
} else if (lift >= 24 || lift <= 39) {
  checkPassword(+prompt("введите пароль"));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ВячеславСиваш Если ответ вам помог, то не забудьте пожалуйста, отметить ответ как принятый (поставить зелённую галочку слева от ответа)